# Variable indicates a quote at beginning without being told to

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to pull out from SQL a value that says 'Inbox'.

```
Function MailboxInbox(ActiveEmail As String, ActiveEmailInbox As String, ValidMailbox, conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset, sConnString As String)
Call OpenSQLCon.ConnectSqlServer(conn, rs, sConnString)
Dim SQL As String
SQL = "Select distinct coalesce(Mailbox_1,Mailbox_2,Mailbox_3) from [MAP].[Config].[TB_SU_MAP_Mailbox_Configuration] where Mailbox_Name ='" & ActiveEmail & "'"
Debug.Print SQL
' Open the connection and execute.
conn.Open sConnString
Set rs = conn.Execute(SQL)
    If rs.EOF = True Or rs.BOF = True Then
        ValidMailbox = 1
        Exit Function
    Else
        ActiveEmailInbox = rs(0)
        Debug.Print ActiveEmailInbox
    End If

'Close SQL
Call CloseSQLCon.CSC(conn, rs, sConnString)
End Function
```

I am connecting to a SQL server, send a query and pull back a single value that I put into the record set. In the SQL table, the value is Inbox, five characters, no ".

However when I populate the variable 'ActiveEmailInbox' with the value from the recordset, it sets it as **"Inbox**

When I use this value later on in the code, I am unable to set the mailbox I want to 'Inbox' as it is set to **"Inbox**. When I print out the value ActiveEmailInbox to the debug window it says Inbox.

The Code with the variable saying it is set to "Inbox
[image: The Code with the variable saying it is set to "Inbox]

The Value of Variable as printed out to the debug window, showing without the "
[image: The Value of Variable as printed out to the debug window, showing without the "]

Comment: The SQL in the image looks different to the one in the posted code on your 2nd image, what is this meant to show?

Comment: what is the recordset count? could you debug.print it? perhaps you get two records or more for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this might be addressing the symptom rather than the actual problem, you could try cutting the first character from the string when it is returned, meaning that the " gets dropped.

```
   ActiveEmailInbox = Right(ActiveEmailInbox , Len(ActiveEmailInbox) - 1)
```

Comment: Not the best solution, because it will cut the first character even if the error does not occur. A better method is to replace the `"` character like so: `active = Replace(ActiveEmailInbox, Chr(34), "")` because it's unlikely the string will ever hold a `"`.